# Import Excel data into SQL Server then prevents repeating data from one column

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I'm trying to import Excel data into SQL Server. And the code below works for me.

But my problem is that it repeats the data row from a specific column name. 
Let's call it column name '1', where in my stored procedure, I added a parameter ('01') which can filter out duplicates even though it is not a unique key column, and yet it is a primary key which shouldn't be duplicated at all.

And I don't know how to execute my stored procedure with a parameter ('01') that has insert select statement in C#... So what I'm trying to do is, just to add an 'If statement' comparing the Excel from the table 'tblname'... is this possible?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace RASImportExcelToSql
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
            ope.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

            if(ope.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName,FileMode.Open);
            IExcelDataReader excelReader =  ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            DataClasses1DataContext conn = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    tblname addtable = new tblname()
                    {       
                        1 = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                        2 = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
                        3 = Convert.ToString(dr[3]),
                        4 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[4]),
                        5 = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[5]),
                        6 = Convert.ToString(dr[6]),
                        7 = Convert.ToString(dr[7]),
                        8 = Convert.ToString(dr[8]),
                        9 = Convert.ToString(dr[9]),
                       10 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[10]),
                       11 = Convert.ToString(dr[11]),
                       12 = Convert.ToBoolean(dr[12])
                    };

                    conn.tblname.InsertOnSubmit(addtable);
                }
            }

            conn.SubmitChanges();

            excelReader.Close();
            stream.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Try");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do....

```
foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        if((1 = Convert.ToString(dr[1)) <> tblname.1)
        {
            tblname addtable = new tblname()
                    {       
                        1 = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                        2 = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
                        3 = Convert.ToString(dr[3]),
                        4 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[4]),
                        5 = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[5]),
                        6 = Convert.ToString(dr[6]),
                        7 = Convert.ToString(dr[7]),
                        8 = Convert.ToString(dr[8]),
                        9 = Convert.ToString(dr[9]),
                       10 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[10]),
                       11 = Convert.ToString(dr[11]),
                       12 = Convert.ToBoolean(dr[12])
                    };

            conn.tblname.InsertOnSubmit(addtable);
        }
        else 
        {  
            MessageBox.Show('None'); 
        }
    }

    conn.SubmitChanges();

    excelReader.Close();
    stream.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Try");
}
```

Is this possible? If not, what other methods should I try? sample codes or links which is similar to this would be really helpful.